# Using LESS in angular2 component

Tags: angular, typescript, less, components

I am trying to use LESS with angular2. I have imported the less.js in index.html
and using the following command in the component

```
less.modifyVars({
                '@currentTheme-bar': '@quote-bar',
                '@currentTheme-button': '@quote-button'
            });
```

I receive an error Cannot find name 'less'

So I tried importing the js into the component like this but it does not work

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import '../../js/less.min.js'

declare var Handsontable: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'advertiser',
  templateUrl: "/templates/advertiser.html"
})



export class AdvertiserComponent {

    quote(){

        if(document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML == "New Quote") {
            less.modifyVars({
                '@currentTheme-bar': '@quote-bar',
                '@currentTheme-button': '@quote-button'
            });
            less.refreshStyles();
------
---------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the way to resolve this is to just create a dummy variable so that typescript can find it. I removed the import statement and added the following :

```
declare var less:any;
```